# webpack-dev-server hot reloading proxy IIS Express with Windows authentication (NTLM Authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, iis, webpack-dev-server

I have created a new `ASP.NET Web Application` -> Web API 2 project with Windows Authentication. This works fine in IIS Express but to get hot reloading for my React front end I have tried to use `webpack-dev-server` and have it proxy my IIS Express. I have used this before both with cookie authentication and token (Bearer) authentication without a problem but with Windows Authentication (NTLM Authentication) it does not work.

Looking at the response from the server I get the expected `401 Unauthorized (401.2)` response with the header `www-authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM` as expected but I don't think the client re-sends the request with `Authorization: NTLM`.

Browsers that I have tried with (Chrome, Firefox and IE) does not give me the normal prompt to enter correct credentials either.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2013/09/20/ntlm-want-to-know-how-it-works/

My settings in webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var proxy = 'localhost:57263';

devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '*': {
            target: 'http://' + proxy,
            changeOrigin: true,
        },
        port: 8080,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at the documentation for `webpack-dev-server Proxy` I saw that they use `http-proxy-middleware`.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy

This led me to this thread and answer:

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/39#issuecomment-330911943

Final solution:

Run:

```
npm install agentkeepalive --save
```

Working code:

```
var proxy = 'localhost:57263';

devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '*': {
            target: 'http://' + proxy,
            changeOrigin: true,
            agent: new agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000 // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
            }),
            onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                var key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            },
        },
        port: 8080,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: Hi Ogglas, How do i get the IISExpress and the webpackdevserver to work together. here is the issue that i face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216912/how-to-configure-webpackdevserver-to-run-an-app-with-asp-net-core-2-0-iisexpress any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanx, works great. But for target with https you need to use HttpsAgent: const agent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;