# How to Configure WebpackDevServer to run an app with ASP.NET CORE 2.0 IISEXPRESS

Tags: c#, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

Using the **ASP.NET Core 2.0** template for creating react app with redux i want to use the webpack-dev-server which is used in the react CRA (CREATE REACT APP) .

The **ASP.NET Core 2.0** app build outputs to a js (Client/Server) file and renders it on a razor page. (cshtml ) (SSR) which on run (F5) runs using the IISEXPRESS.

I want to run the same using **IISEXPRESS** but using the **WebpackDevServer** since the execution in it faster especially after the initial build .

I have tried the following by adding a proxy to my package.json

[image: proxy settings]

[image: C# code with fixed port no]

The template provides a way to do server side rendering of react app. The goal is to have a faster incremental build on changes to files since i have a lot of files .

The app when run with the same code using Create React App renders faster without any issues.

On the other hand the default HMR (Hot Module Replacement) given by the ASP.NET Core template renders sometimes and throws an error, where in we would need to rebuild the entire thing once again consuming a lot of time.

[image]

Anyway i could get the WebPackDevServer to work with IISExpress ?
Thanks in Advance for any pointers regarding the same.

Comment: did you get any answer? how did you solve it? I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: Used the asp.net core 2.2 template it had a more cleaner way where the Client app was seperated from core app

Comment: Do you have an example of how you achieved it because I'm using the .net core 3 version and don't want to use react-scripts and instead roll my own webpack and am totally stuck getting it to run